# Porque nao esta entrando no if?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Quero realiza uma operacao se a 2° posicao de um string for maiuscula, mas nao esta entrando no if, e acho que o if nao esta correto.

Exemplo:

usuario digita `4A6` entao neste string a 2° posicao é maiuscula. Como faco para dizer que a posicao que o usuario digitou é maiuscula?

Segue o codigo para esclarecer

```
public class JogoMatematica {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Quantidade de caso de teste: ");
    int qtd = entrada.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i <  qtd;  i++){ 
        System.out.println("Digite os 3 caracteres: "); 
        // exemplo de entrada 4A6. A letra "A" eh maiuscula
        String caractere = entrada.next(); 
        // pega o elemento da posicao 0
        int valorInt1 = Integer.parseInt(caractere.substring(0,1));
        // pega o elemento da posicao 2
        int valorInt2 = Integer.parseInt(caractere.substring(2)); 
        // pega o elemento na posicao 1
        // se a letra "A" for maiuscula entra no if 
        if(caractere.substring(1,2).toUpperCase().equals(caractere)){ 
             System.out.println("String maiuscula na posicao ");     
        } 

        }
```

Comment: Você está fazendo a comparação de `A` com `4A6`. `String`s são imutáveis, então `caractere.substring(1,2)` está criando um novo objeto.

Comment: Tenta usar no seu ultimo if  `char c = caractere.charAt(1);
   if (Character.isUpperCase(c))`

Comment: Você está comparando uma substring com a entrada toda, aqui: `if(caractere.substring(1,2).toUpperCase().equals(caractere))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu código está comparando o caractere 2 com a string completa digitada pelo usuário, por isso nunca irá funcionar:

```
if(caractere.substring(1,2).toUpperCase().equals(caractere)){
```

O que você precisa fazer é apenas verificar se o segundo caracter é maiúsculo, para isso você pode usar o método `Character.isUpperCase`. Seu teste ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
if (Character.isUpperCase(caractere.charAt(1))) {
  ...
}
```